# Proper position of imports & definitions in called scripts?

Tags: python, import, call, external

I have one script that calls another - let's call them `master.py` and `fetch.py`. I suppose the second script could be integrated into the first, but it does have distinct functionality - so keeping them separate seems like a good way to force myself to learn how to call outside scripts.

Here's the basic structure of fetch.py:

```
<import block>
infiles = <paths>

arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.dirname(infile)
ws = arcpy.env.workspace
newfile_list = []

def main():
    name = <name>
    if not arcpy.Exists(name + ".gdb"):
        global ws
        new_gdb = DM.CreateFileGDB(ws, name + ".gdb")
        newfile_list.append(new_gdb)
    other_func1()
    other_func2()
    print "\nNew files from fetch.py:"
    for i in newfile_list:
        print "    " + i

def other_func1():
    stuff
def other_func2():
    stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

And master.py:

```
<import block>
infiles = <paths>

def f1():
    stuff
def f2():
    stuff

import fetch
fetch.main()
f1()
f2()
```

The problems, concerning placement of the import block & file definitions of fetch.py:

- When I put them inside `main()` and run it as a standalone script, my arcpy functions don't work because my various imports haven't run yet. Putting them ahead of main() and making them global, solves this problem.
- But when I put them outside of `main()` as you see here, I get an error saying the local variable `ws` is referenced before assignment. I think this may have to do with my calling `fetch.main()`, where the initial lines don't get read. (I was able to make it work by declaring `global ws`, but don't know if this is advisable.)

How do I structure fetch.py so that the import statements and file definitions get read, both when run as a standalone script and when called?

Comment: put in question full error message and all places where you use `ws`. Seems you use `ws = ws + ...` before you do `ws = ...`

Comment: Sure, I'm confident that's the problem (since I was able to get around the problem by adding `global ws`). But that still leaves me with the quandry that in getting my script to work for external calls, I break its ability to be run stand-alone (and vice versa). So given that, how do I structure the code so import block & early assignments get read whether running standalone or called externally?

Comment: I do not the understand why you would want to structure your code like you do, because you do not explain clearly what you are trying to accomplish. Usually all imports in any module can and should be placed at the beginning of the file unless you have a good reason not to. So there should be a good reason why you need to do a module level import in the middle of a file. You also do a lot of other stuff on the module level, which might complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks. The actual 'master' script runs a geoprocessing routine on a patch of seafloor elevation data. The 'fetch' script does a series of calculations to determine orientation of linear features on the seafloor. This orientation is used to properly orient directionally-sensitive analysis of the seafloor.

I'm keeping the 'fetch' script separate because finding feature orientation seems like a useful stand-alone tool down the road.

I first tried putting the import block at top but got an error saying `ws` is referenced before assignment. Adding `global ws` works, but is this advisable?

Comment: @OliverBestwalter: Not sure if you saw my response, above. Now tagging you so you're alerted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rewriting your code for you, I will try to point you to some ideas from the developer philosophy toolkit to get you on the way how to refine your approach.

My feeling is that you should contemplate [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) and [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) when thinking about your code.

In your comment you write:

> I'm keeping the 'fetch' script separate because finding feature orientation seems like a useful stand-alone tool down the road.

Like I say: YAGNI and KISS: If you need it as a standalone tool in the future then split it out in the future. For now keep it simple and put the code that belongs together in one module and make it callable exactly the way you need it. When you work with it and understand the problem better and see what else is needed, you can then add other ways of calling your script. There is no reason why you shouldn't keep all the code in one module while it is still manageable and just add different ways to call it.

If the time comes that you want to organize your code into several modules you can refactor it in a way that you pull out the things you do on the module level at the moment (either into functions or maybe even classes). Then you can control exactly what should happen when and you can control the order of things better.

As further reading in regards to structuring a Python project I would recommend the [pypa sample project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) and [Starting A Python Project The Right Way](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/02/04/starting-a-python-project-the-right-way/). The problems you have with imports will likely cease to exist if you structure your code and your project in a sensible, pythonic way.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response; seems sensible. I've been trying KISS in that these scripts started independently, addressing different parts of the problem and I've kept them separate in part to avoid potentially conflicting variables. I've also had a nagging sense from my readings that I was violating the 'right' way to do things by not building methods into functions and modules. I'm a novice & my default is in-line coding. I was hoping to learn by doing. But perhaps I've crossed a line where it's now simpler to combine them, as you suggest. Thanks for the links & perspective.

Comment: You are following the natural progression from simple scripting on the module level to introducing functions and other ways of organizing your code. That is one of the reasons why Python is such a great language for beginners.  Maybe the next step in improving your script(s) would be to think about when and how `ws` should be set and how to pass it around and how to deal with newfile_list because these are the objects that make your live harder as they are executed on import.

Comment: Also: use a visual debugger to step through your code to get a bettter understanding for what is happening when ([pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) has a great debugger). Also [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/) is great for visualizing what's going on Maybe you would also benefit from trying to get some feedback on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm moving ahead as you suggested to integrate things into one script. 

But it's also helpful for me to learn rules of thumb, where possible, to help me as I go. Given the original challenge I posed, if I were to call one script with another, it's generally best to have the import block at the top level, not embedded into `main()`, correct? In which case I'd call `global ws` as I did above to make it available within `main()`?

Comment: I think this is starting to be out of scope for the comments section, but you do not call scripts from one another in python. You import modules or packages and then you call their functions or create objects from their classes, etc. It's important to understand the concepts and learn the right terminology, so that you can ask questions in a way that they are understood and you can be helped.

Comment: You should also just create `ws` exactly where you need it the first time and when you need it somewhere else you pass it to where you need it e.g. as a parameter of a function. If you have more questions along those lines, I suggest you write on [Python Tutor].(https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) mailing list.